# Two HTML forms submitted by PHP trigger each other

Tags: php, html, forms

i've got 2 forms on one page, but when I press submit one the other is actioned.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
  Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" name="getNameSubmit">
</form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {



    // collect value of input field

    if(isset($_REQUEST['fname']) && $_REQUEST['fname']!="")
        {   
         $name = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['fname']);
              if (empty($name)) {
                echo "Hello dear user.";
            } else {
                echo "Hello $name";
            }
    }

}

?>
```

and

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
  Full text: <input type="text" name="stringtoreplace" value="">
  Word(s) to change: <input type="text" name="wordstochange" value="">
  Change to: <input type="text" name="wordstoinput" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="wordReplaceSubmit">
</form>

<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {



    // collect value of input field -- the if(isset) stops a pre-comparison that throws an E_NOTICE level error

    if(isset($_REQUEST['stringtoreplace']) && $_REQUEST['stringtoreplace']!="")
    {
     $stringoutput = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['stringtoreplace']);
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['wordstochange']) && $_REQUEST['wordstochange']!="")
    {
     $tochange = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['wordstochange']);
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['wordstoinput']) && $_REQUEST['wordstoinput']!="")
    {
     $changeto = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['wordstoinput']);
    }


    if (empty($stringoutput)) {
        echo "Please enter your text and the words to change.";
    } else {
        echo str_replace($tochange, $changeto, $stringoutput);
    }
}

?>
```

How can I get one to action without triggering the other? The function and placement isn't a factor here, I'm just doing some practice, but would be nice ton understand why this happens and how to resolve.

Comment: If you really want to keep all in one PHP file, just add an hidden input with a different name/value on each form and use it to distinguish which one was submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's start on why this is happening.

The `action` parameter of an HTML tells the browser which URL to send the POST request with the form data. In your case, it's `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, which is the current PHP script. You use the same for both forms.

When one of the forms is submitted, your PHP script gets called, and all the PHP in the script gets executed. The first part (the one after the first form) checks `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")`, decides that yes, it was a POST request, and tries to proceed. After that, the second part (the one after the second form), uses the exact same check, decides that yes, it was a POST request, and tries to proceed too.

Ideally, it would be cleaner to have two different pages to process two different forms; but if you prefer to keep all in the same page, you have a couple of different options to distinguish between the two.

1) Use a different query parameter in the action attribute for each form, as suggested by @sauhardnc. The forms would look like:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?form=form1">
...
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?form=form2">
```

while the PHP side would do something like

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if ($_GET['form'] == 'form1') {
        // code for form1
    } else {
        // code for form2
    }
}
```

2) Use a different input in each form. The forms would look like:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="form1">
</form>
...
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="form2">
</form>
```

while the PHP side would do something like

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if ($_REQUEST['form'] == 'form1') {
        // code for form1
    } else {
        // code for form2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>` gives the current URL, so because they're in the same page, it causes the problem. You can check this on inspecting the page `Ctrl + Shift + i` then clicking on `Elements` on Chrome.

One solution might be to give different URLs to both the forms or use parameters on post request. Eg.- `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?form=form1';?>` & `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?form=form2';?>`

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if(isset($_GET['form'])){
        if($_GET['form'] == 'form1'){
            //code for form1
        }else{
            //code for form2
        }
    }
}
```